# iPad Safari popup issue

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

I am using window.open to open a popup in my page...

Now the issue is the popup gets displayed only if the user has changed the settings to allow popups...

What is the fix if I want to show the popup whether or not the user has blocked/allowed it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has blocked popups, your website will not be able to launch them.

Comment: I am sure there will be some alternate way of coding or calling the popup...Isn't there?

Comment: You could try something in the same window, such as jQuery UI dialogs - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/, or something else overlay-ish.  The crux of the matter, however, is that if a user has prohibited popups in their global settings, you cannot bypass that.